# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

Tags: python

Tengo ubuntu 20.04, he instalado ya pygame varias veces, pero en todas y cada una, al ejecutar el codigo, me aparece el siguiente mensaje ...

```
  File "/home/santiago/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

Ya probe con desinstalar y volver a instalar varias veces, no funciona. Aparentemente se trata de una dependencia que no tengo instalada, alguna idea ??

Comment: Tu archivo se llama pygame.py?

Comment: No, se llama main.py

Comment: Prueba a instalarlo con `sudo apt install python3-pygame`

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace ya lo intente, lo mismo ...

Comment: Hay una subcarpeta en la carpeta donde esta el main.py cuyo nombre sea "pygame"?

Comment: @DanteS. negativo, de hecho probe tambien en otro archivo en otra carpeta y para exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Esto (en ingles) responde a tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224385/pygame-no-module-called-pygame-base

Comment: @DanteS. negativo, ya intente eso varias veces tambien ..